# ASP.NET MVC 5: My application doesn't read the data from my database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I tried to follow a tutorial on ASP.NET MVC 5, but when I try to print on the page all the data from my "Customers" table, it doesn't show anything, even though my table is not empty. I use the variable "ApplicationDbContext _context" for this and pass it to the view, where I print the contents. What am I missing?

My Customers Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Vidly.ViewModels;
using Vidly.Models;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace Vidly.Controllers
{
    public class CustomersController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public CustomersController()
        {
            _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            _context.Dispose();
        }
        // GET: Customers
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var customers = _context.Customers.ToList();

            var movies = new List<Movie>
            {
                new Movie {Id=1, Name="Movie1"},
                new Movie {Id=2, Name="Movie2"}
            };

            var viewModel = new RandomMovieViewModel { Movies = movies, Customers = customers };

            return View(viewModel);
            
        }
        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            var customers = _context.Customers.ToList();
            if (customers == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            ViewData["CustId"] = id;
            var viewModel = new RandomMovieViewModel { Customers = customers };
            return View(viewModel);
        }
    }
}
```

After I enabled migrations, my IdentityModels.cs files was missing, unlike in the tutorial I followed, so I created it myself:

```
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System;

namespace Vidly.Models
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {

        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    //public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {

        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
}
```

I was also missing some tables that were built automatically in the tutorial, like AspNetRoles and AspNetUserRoles. I don't know why and how to fix this.

My Customers View Index:

```
@model Vidly.ViewModels.RandomMovieViewModel 

@{

    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <td scope="row">
            <a href="/Home/Index">
                Vidly
            </a>
        </td>

        <td scope="row">
            <a href="/Customers">
                Customers
            </a>
        </td>

        <td scope="row">
            <a href="/Movies">
                Movies
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>


<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Customer
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var cust in Model.Customers)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="/Customers/Details/cust.Id">
                    cust.Name
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Edit: I solved the problem! Turns out I had "No authentication" on when I created my ASP.NET MVC file. I reacreated it, switching authentication to "Individual user accounts" and it worked. Thank you very much to those who tried to help me.

Comment: add ur startup file....

Comment: If you mean the file called "startup.cs", then I can't find it. I might not have it at all. Do you have any advice on this?

Comment: no you were right the startup.cs is what i was after... I want to see how you are registering you DI for the context which will be done in the startup.cs file

Answer (score 0):

When you add identity services to your project, some database migration files should be added under [Base Folder]/Data/Migrations/ you want to run these against your database to update the tables.  When you update the package, any database changes will be put in these migrations.

In your application config file (appsettings.json) you should have a connection string to create the application db context

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=servername;Database=databaseName;User Id=username;Password=password;",
  }
```

Add a new entry to your config file

```
"InitialiseIdentityDatabase": "true"
```

We are going to use this to tell you server to initialise the database on start up.  After we have created the tables, you can set this to false.

Create a new function in you startup.cs add a new function

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Setup the identity database
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="app"></param>
    private void InitializeDatabase(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
        {
            serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>().Database.Migrate();
            // If there are no user identities, create some default ones here.
        }
    }
```

In your "public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)" add the following line

```
if (Configuration.GetValue<string>("InitialiseIdentityDatabase") != null && Configuration.GetValue<string>("InitialiseIdentityDatabase").ToUpper() == "TRUE")
                InitializeDatabase(app);
```

When the configuration value is set to true, the service will run the migration script to create the identity tables in your database.  If you update the identity package, set this to true again and apply any migration updates.

Comment: From what I've researched, I should have my appsettings.json file in my Properties folder. It is not there. All I have is a file called "AssemblyInfo.cs". Should I create the appsettings.json file? I also don't think I have the startup.cs file.